# How do I change the UI language in Snow Leapoard?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I'd like to change my MacBook's languages of the UI. How would I do that in Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open System Preferences, and then Language & Text. Drag the language you want on top and then log-off (or restart) your computer.

[image]

Comment: Do some languages need to be "downloaded" via an update or something?

Comment: In Snow Leopard languages came in the Install CD.